# What are the advantages of NAS distros in SOHO environment

Tags: distribution-choice, nas

There are a few distros dedicated to being a NAS (e.g., [FreeNAS](http://www.freenas.org) and [OMV](http://www.openmediavault.org)). What advantages do these types of distros provide for use in a SOHO environment over a typical customized server install of BSD/Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Maintenance costs. Especially if you are not very familiar with Linux administration. NAS distributions will contain all needed packages out of the box, and also usually will have a web interface for easy configuration.